# Query Returning value as 0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am trying to execute following PL/SQL script in SQL Developer. The loop should return count of nulls but somehow everytime it is returning 0. 
set serveroutput on

```
DECLARE

--v_count number;
v_count_null number;

BEGIN
execute immediate 'select count(*) from SP_MOSAIX' into v_count;

FOR  i in (select column_name from all_tab_COLUMNS where table_name = 'SP_MOSAIX')
LOOP
select count(*) into v_count_null from SP_MOSAIX  where i.column_name IS NULL ;
dbms_output.put_line(v_count_null);

END LOOP;

END;
```

So when I run this, following output is what i get:

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

But if I manually execute the query subsituting column_name I get the result.

```
select count(*) into v_count_null from SP_MOSAIX  where i.column_name IS NULL;
```

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: It is returning 0 becuase i.column_name is treated as variable and not column. Now question is how can i make it as actual column vaule and not variable

Comment: In the second select statement, there is no alias "i" for the table SP_MOSAIX. See SQL Alias: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here that you need to be aware of. Firstly, as you allude to, your COUNT query is executing using the value of i.column_name, which is never NULL.

Secondly, `COUNT(*)` returns the number of **rows** that match your `WHERE` clause condition, regardless of `NULL` values. If you want to count how many `NOT NULL` values there are in a particular column, you must `COUNT` values in that column explicitly.

Please see the following example ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30709/9)):

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE null_col_vals (
  col_without_nulls INTEGER NOT NULL
, col_with_nulls INTEGER
, col_with_mix INTEGER  
)
/

INSERT INTO null_col_vals (col_without_nulls, col_with_nulls, col_with_mix)
VALUES (1, NULL, NULL)
/

INSERT INTO null_col_vals (col_without_nulls, col_with_nulls, col_with_mix)
VALUES (1, NULL, 1)
/

INSERT INTO null_col_vals (col_without_nulls, col_with_nulls, col_with_mix)
VALUES (1, NULL, NULL)
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(col_without_nulls) col_without_nulls
, COUNT(col_with_nulls) col_with_nulls
, COUNT(col_with_mix) col_with_mix
, COUNT(*) all_rows
FROM null_col_vals
```

**Results**:

```
| COL_WITHOUT_NULLS | COL_WITH_NULLS | COL_WITH_MIX | ALL_ROWS |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                 3 |              0 |            1 |        3 |
```

As you can see, `COUNT(*)` always returns the number of rows present, but the others vary in results depending on whether `NULL` values are present in the specified column or not.

You'll need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to convert your column name into part of the query. Something like this might do the job:

**Query 2**:

```
DECLARE

  l_count INTEGER;

BEGIN

  FOR r_col IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM all_tab_columns atc
    WHERE atc.table_name = 'NULL_COL_VALS'
  )
  LOOP

    dbms_output.put_line(r_col.column_name);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(' || r_col.column_name || ') FROM null_col_vals' 
    INTO l_count;

    dbms_output.put_line(l_count);

  END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful explanation and help... My problem got solved... thnx..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic SQL, which will allow you to reference each column:

```
FOR  i in (select column_name from all_tab_COLUMNS where table_name = 'SP_MOSAIX')
LOOP
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from SP_MOSAIX  where '||i.column_name||' IS NULL'
     into v_count_null ;
    dbms_output.put_line(i.column_name||' = '||v_count_null);

END LOOP;
```