# how to make a loop for all columns of a table?

Tags: oracle, loops, select, plsql

I have a table EMPLOYEES, i need to make a loop, on every step of the loop I use dbms_output.put_line(column_name)

How can I make this?

Comment: What do want to do *do* with the columns in this loop?  If you want to do anything other than just display the column name you will need to use dynamic SQL.  Have a look at the answer to a recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13483646/146325

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found this solution

```
begin
   for rec in (SELECT column_name 
               FROM all_tab_columns 
               WHERE owner = 'HR'
               AND table_name = 'EMPLOYEES')
   loop
       dbms_output.put_line(rec.column_name);
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cursor as below:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
 var_col1 varchar2(30) ;
 num_col2 number ;  

 CURSOR cur
 is       
  select var_col ,num_col
  from table
  where <conditions>;

begin
   open cur;
   fetch cur into var_col1,num_col2;

   LOOP
    fetch cur into var_col1,num_col2;
       EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
       dbms_output.put_line( var_col1||'         '||num_col2);
   END LOOP;

   close cur;  
end;
```

here is another solution:

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
  FOR  cur in ( select var_col ,num_col from table where <conditions>)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(cur.var_col||' = '||cur.num_col);
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: @APC `loop for all columns of a table` In my solution there is a loop and display columns from table step by step. Do you think he wants to something else?

Comment: @APC I see you edited David Kakauridze's posts. I'm sure his first solution missed the point.

Answer (score 0):

Of course You can rewrite this SELECT example with WHERE after table_name. I dont compiled this code but I thinks its OK. Change ID_Employee and Name for your atributes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AAA_TEST
    IS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE 
            v_id NUMBER :=0;
            v_name VARCHAR2(25);

            CURSOR cursorMails IS
                 SELECT Id_Employee,Name FROM EMPLOYEES;  

            BEGIN
                           OPEN cursorMails;

                               LOOP

                                    FETCH cursorMails INTO v_id, v_name;
                                         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of Employee: ' || v_id || ' Name Employee: ' || v_name);
                               EXIT WHEN cursorMails%NOTFOUND;
                               END LOOP;
                           CLOSE cursorMails;
            END;
    END;
    /
```